# Answer Set Programming - Make a Fact INVALID

Tags: knowledge-representation, logic, declarative-programming

I have a question regarding **Answer Set Programming** on how to make an existing ***fact*** invalid, when there is already (also) a ***default statement*** present in the Knowledge Base.

For example, there are two persons `seby` and `andy`, one of them is able to drive at once. The scenario can be that `seby` can drive as seen in Line 3 but  let's say, after his license is cancelled he cannot drive anymore, hence we now have Lines 4 to 7 and meanwhile `andy` learnt driving, as seen in Line 7. Line 6 shows only one person can drive at a time, besides showing `seby` and `andy` are not the same.

> ```
> 1 person(seby).
> 2 person(andy).
> 3 drives(seby).
> 4 drives(seby) :- person(seby), not ab(d(drives(seby))), not -drives(seby).
> 5 ab(d(drives(seby))).
> 6 -drives(P) :- drives(P0), person(P), P0 != P.
> 7 drives(andy).
> ```

In the above program, Lines 3 and 4 contradict with each other, and the Clingo solver (which I use) obviously outputs `UNSATISFIABLE`.

Having said all these, deleting Line 3 and getting the problem solved is not what I'm epecting. The intention behind asking this question is to know whether it is possible now to make Line 3 somehow invalid to let Line 4 do its duty.

However, Line 4 can also be written as:

> 4 drives(P) :- person(P), not ab(d(drives(P))), not -drives(P).

Thanks a lot in advance.